# View plain text field causing rendering issues for translations

Tags: views, theming, 9

Our news section has a plain text field for article header. At the time of development this seemed like a good idea, however, having gone live, some languages like French has special characters which is now causing rendering issues as example:

[image]

Is rendered as:

[image]

I understand why this is happening as text fields are "escaped" for security reasons. The problem here is one of hindsight:

1. We cannot delete the field or "convert" the field to a formatted text as that would require all languages to redo all of the articles
2. We cannot add any additional filters in the "view" as there isn't a filter allowing me to say "please allow certain characters" as in this case l' is considered an escaped character in the database.

I assume my only option is to try and override the value in my twig file: (views-view-fields--news.html.twig):

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="card newscard"> {{ fields.field_summary_image.content }}
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">
                <a href="{{ fields.view_node.content|render|striptags|trim }}">{{ fields.field_article_title.content|render|striptags }}</a>
            </h5>
            <p>{{ fields.created.content|render|striptags|trim }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have however tried to obtain the raw value but cannot get the raw value as this is a rendered "field" (which renders the wrapping HTML along with content).

I have also tried to move this to the unformatted view (views-view-unformatted--news.html.twig):

```
<div class="card-deck" id="ajaxnewscontainer">
    {% for row in rows %}
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card newscard"> {{ fields.field_summary_image.content }}
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">
                        <a href="{{ fields.view_node.content|render|striptags|trim }}">{{ fields.field_article_title.content|render|striptags }}</a>
                    </h5>
                    <p>{{ fields.created.content|render|striptags|trim }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

However, in this scenario I am not getting any values as doing a {{ dump(row) }} renders my 32GB of RAM useless so cannot determine how to obtain the "row" array elements so that I can hopefully end up getting the "raw" value of fields.field_article_title.content|render|striptags

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd recommend against this approach, it never ends well. Instead add a new formatted field, and write an update hook which transfers the content from the old to the new.

Comment: Why are you rendering with `|render|striptags|trim`? Afaik, that will always cause you to see encoded html entities.

Comment: But why use `&#39;` in the first place? Type the apostrophe with you keyboard. There are many plain text fields in Drupal which are translated, most prominently entity labels.

Comment: @sonfd Yes, this is probably the problem. It's not as I suspected. The translation contains the apostrophe as ASCII character, This is converted to an HTML entity by the default XSS filter applied to all plain text fields  and then it is escaped a second time by this Twig filter.

Comment: So normally translated plain text fields don't cause any issue.

Comment: Without the |render, the field is blank.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this has anything to do with translations other than your translation is the version of the node that happens to have an apostrophe in this field.

The issue is because you are rendering your field with `|render|striptags|trim` like:

```
{{ fields.created.content|render|striptags|trim }}
```

This will always cause issues where encoded html entities are displayed.

From @4uk4 in a comment above:

> The translation contains the apostrophe as ASCII character, this is converted to an HTML entity by the default XSS filter applied to all plain text fields and then it is escaped a second time by this Twig filter.

To resolve, render your field without using `|render|striptags|trim`, i.e. just use:

```
{{ fields.created.content }}
```

Comment: Without the |render the result is blank

Comment: Are you using `{{ fields.created.content }}` or `{{ fields.created.content|striptags|trim }}`. The latter won't work.